# JQuery ':contains' convert it into Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

My problem is, the code is written in Jquery, I want to convert it into a Javascript but I cant find the documentation of javascript about contains.

If you want to know how this works, then let me explain. Inside a table there are words "CRITICAL" and "SAFE", This will count how many CRITICAL are there inside the table. So the expected output here is:

```
6
```

Btw adding class name or ID is not an option, so as possible please dont use Class name or ID name.

**file.php**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>SAFE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>SAFE</td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JS FILE**

```
var test = $('td:contains(CRTICAL)');

console.log(test.size());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a reusable function that accepts the elements array and text that needs to be searched, then return the count from that function:

```js
var test = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td');

function getCount(elem, text) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if (elem[i].innerText.trim().indexOf(text) !== -1) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}


console.log('CRITICAL-->' + getCount(test, 'CRITICAL'));
console.log('SAFE-->' + getCount(test, 'SAFE'));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>CRITICAL </td>
    <td>CRITICAL </td>
    <td>CRITICAL </td>
    <td>SAFE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SAFE</td>
    <td>CRITICAL </td>
    <td>CRITICAL </td>
    <td>CRITICAL </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be done in one line of code

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td")).filter(el => el.innerText.indexOf("CRITICAL") !== -1)
```

**Explanation:**

1. `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td"))` convert Node List return by javascript selector to an array so that you can use `filter` function
2. `.filter(el => el.innerText.indexOf("CRITICAL") !== -1` filter out any td element that doesn't contain "CRITICAL"

**Snippet:**

```js
var test = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td")).filter(el => el.innerText.indexOf("CRITICAL") !== -1);

console.log(test.length);
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>SAFE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>SAFE</td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom function for it.

```js
let word = 'CRITICAL';
function contains(elements,string){
  let count= 0;
  elms = Array.from(elements);
  elms.forEach(elm => {
    if(elm.innerText.includes(string)) count++;
  })  
  return count;
}
console.log(contains(document.querySelectorAll('table td'),word));
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>SAFE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>SAFE</td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
 <td>CRITICAL </td>
</tr>
</table>
```